# Executing BCP from an Azure PHP web app

Tags: php, shell, azure, bcp, shell-exec

Update: after a bunch of searching, it appears that Azure may restrict my ability to execute certain shell commands. I'm currently on a Standard 1 Web App plan - what do I have to do to be able to use the BCP utility through PHP?

So I have a PHP script running on my Azure web app and I've been trying to use BCP to upload data. I was able to run the command successfully via the Azure console but am having trouble running it through PHP.

PHP Code:

```
$upload_dir = '../uploads';
$test = shell_exec("bcp [database].[dbo].[Group] IN $upload_dir/working/Group.csv -S <server>; -T -f $upload_dir/format/Group.fmt -F2");
die($test);
```

When I run this, I receive no response from the script and querying the DB indicates that the upload was unsuccessful. When I try a simpler test using

```
$test = shell_exec("echo 'Hello World'");
die($test);
```

I receive the expected output, 'Hello World'.

For file structure, the PHP script is located in the wwwroot/scripts folder, and the CSV and FMT files are located in wwwroot/uploads/working/Group.csv and wwwroot/uploads/format/Group.fmt, respectively.

Is there something I'm missing when trying to execute shell commands through PHP? I'm pretty new to this, so I appreciate all the help!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

According your description, it seems that you copied `bcp.exe` and `bcp.dll` to Azure Web Apps directory, and attempted to use shell env to execute the `bcp` commands. As the default directory path of Azure Console is the root directory of Azure Web Apps, so I suppose your application's structure will look like:

```
wwwroot/
       bcp.exe
       bcp.dll
       scripts/
       uploads/
       ...
```

According your code snippet, your php script in `scripts` folder cannot find the bcp command, so you got the blank page.

You can try to move the `bcp.exe` and `bcp.dll` files into the scripts folder, or modify the shell command e.g. `../bcp db.dbo.table in ...`

If I have any misunderstanding of your question, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for answering - since the Azure web app server runs on a Windows Server, BCP is installed by default. The problem was that the server wouldn't allow me to run shell_exec with bcp or other commands such as ls. I ended up creating a separate virtual machine where I would have the ability to run BCP.